# Making all text on a page that uses Semantic UI larger

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I’m using Semantic UI framework.

I’d like to make all of the text marginally larger on a page as I don’t have too many elements and it looks silly with such small default text.

How would I go about making this change on my page?

Comment: What have you tried? You flag as 'css', that would be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I thought I could just use the simple, compiled css provided by Semantic UI as I didn't need anything fancy: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS .

It turns out, that was the limitation to making theme changes (like making all fonts larger).

So, to fix it, I installed semantic ui using npm as described here: https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/build-tools.html

Then added the following to `site/collections/form.variables`:

`less
@fontSize : 18px;
@labelFontSize: 18px;`

Then I built the dist files using `gulp build`.